# NewForm.aspx in Sharepoint Designer with Lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have Two Lists

`List1{Department Name,Status(Active,Close)}` And `List2{Student Name , Department(as lookup field link with Department Name on List1)}`

My requirment is create `NewForm.aspx` for the List2 , but if I want to show on the ComboBox of lookup field (Department) Only Items with condition Status=Active.

Is There Any Way To do this By SharePoint Designer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In List1 Create a calculated field and name `ActiveDepartment` and use formula

```
=IF(Status="Active",[Department Name],"")
```

Now in the lookup field link it to `ActiveDepartment` field instead of `Department Name`

Comment: Thank You Mr.Amal Hashim 
only replace comma with semicolon  .